# Resharper Evaluation

Tags: object, initialization, resharper

I am evaluating resharper and I noticed a quirk in the software. I am not sure if this is truly a quirk.
Here's my code:

```
var oc = new OracleConnection();
```

Resharper is suggesting using an Object Initializer for this instead of new keyword. How do you use an object initializer for a connection? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you click on the suggestion and Resharper will do the correction for you?

I guess the code you have is something like:

```
var oc = new OracleConnection();    
oc.Blabla = blabla;
```

And what Resharper will do if you let it, is:

```
var oc = new OracleConnection { Blabla = blabla };
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misreading the message.

Resharper is telling you to use an object initializer to *set properties* after constructing it, like this:

```
var oc = new OracleConnection { ConnectionString = "..." };
```

Also, you should close the connection using a `using` statement.